# Predicting not possible due to mismatch of features

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, sklearn-pandas, joblib

I use sklearn to create a logistic regression model based on a xlsx-file. I remove some target and redundant features from the dataset.
Now I want to make a prediction and want to get the label based on a new xlsx-file for every row of the file.

I'm able to store and load the model. After running the prediction, I get an issue:

*'X has 37 features per sample; expecting 44'*

What's going wrong? Thank you for your hints.

```
...
## TRAIN

target = df_HR['Fluktuation'].copy()
type(target)

# remove the target feature and redundant features from the dataset
df_HR.drop(['Fluktuation', 'FTE', 'Mitarbeiternummer',
            'StandardStunden', 'Volljaehrig'], axis=1, inplace=True)
print('Size of Full dataset is: {}'.format(df_HR.shape))

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df_HR,
                                                    target,
                                                    test_size=0.25,
                                                    random_state=7,
                                                    stratify=target) 
## CREATE MODEL AND STORE IT

kfold = model_selection.KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=7)
modelCV = LogisticRegression(solver='liblinear',
                             class_weight="balanced", 
                             random_state=7)
scoring = 'roc_auc'
results = model_selection.cross_val_score(
    modelCV, X_train, y_train, cv=kfold, scoring=scoring)
print(" Logistic Regression algorithm AUC score (STD): %.2f (%.2f)" % (results.mean(), results.std()))

param_grid = {'C': np.arange(1e-03, 2, 0.01)} # hyper-parameter list to fine-tune
log_gs = GridSearchCV(LogisticRegression(solver='liblinear', # setting GridSearchCV
                                         class_weight="balanced", 
                                         random_state=7),
                      iid=True,
                      return_train_score=True,
                      param_grid=param_grid,
                      scoring='roc_auc',
                      cv=10)

log_grid = log_gs.fit(X_train, y_train)
log_opt = log_grid.best_estimator_
results = log_gs.cv_results_

model_file_name = '%s/model.pkl' % modelFolder
joblib.dump(log_gs, model_file_name)

## LOAD MODEL AND PREDICT NEW XLSX FILE
...
df_HRE = df_sourcefileE.copy()
dfColumnsE = df_HRE.columns

leE = LabelEncoder()

le_countE = 0

for col in df_HRE.columns[1:]:
    if df_HRE[col].dtype == 'object':
        if len(list(df_HRE[col].unique())) <= 2:
            leE.fit(df_HRE[col])
            df_HRE[col] = leE.transform(df_HRE[col])
            le_countE += 1
print('{} columns label encoded.'.format(le_countE))

df_HRE = pd.get_dummies(df_HRE, drop_first=True)
#print('df_HRE',df_HRE)

# import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 5))
HRE_col = list(df_HRE.columns)
#print('datensatz HRE: ', df_HRE)
HRE_col.remove('Fluktuation')
for col in HRE_col:
    df_HRE[col] = df_HRE[col].astype(float)
    df_HRE[[col]] = scaler.fit_transform(df_HRE[[col]])
df_HRE['Fluktuation'] = pd.to_numeric(df_HRE['Fluktuation'], downcast='float')

targetE = df_HRE['Fluktuation'].copy()
type(targetE)

df_HRE.drop(['Fluktuation', 'FTE', 'Mitarbeiternummer',
    'StandardStunden', 'Volljaehrig'], axis=1, inplace=True)


# apply the whole pipeline to data
pred = loaded_model.predict(df_HRE)
print (pred)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like when you trained the initial model you had 44 columns of data (features).  In order to predict using this same model you need the same number of predictors otherwise.

For instance, say your model was originally 3 variables (x1, x2, x3) where each variable is a column in the original dataset, then the regression formula would be something like

```
y=A*x1 + B*x2 + C*x3 + D
```

If you don't supply x2 or x3 when you try to predict, there won't be a way to apply the formula.

So you have two options, retrain the model without the seven extra features (those features that appear in the training set and not in the prediction set) or add these same seven features to the prediction model with NULL values (not recommended).